# Automatically view specifc database in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

We have an SQL database that is hosted remotely and I use SQL Server Management Studio to manage everything.  Being that we are on a shared server there are many other databases on the same server.  Is there a way to automatically expand the object explorer to my database upon connection? or possibly filter the databases to show only mine?

Specifying the "Connect to database" in the Connection Properties does not achieve this.

Comment: I'd love to see a way to do this in SSMS too!  I have yet to come up with a way to do it at the SSMS level, although there are suggestions how it could be done with your login account on the server itself.  We can filter tables in a DB (although the filter isn't remembered on subsequent connections), but we can't seem to create a filter on the list of DBs on a server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few command line switches for Management Studio [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx)

The exe is here on my PC: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe".

Use the -U switch to specify a login and -S to specify a server and this will open a new query file connected to this logins default database.  This can be changed using the alter command, i.e.

```
alter login sa with default_database = master
```

This isn't quite connecting Object Explorer but it may help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: A server doesn't have a default database. A login can.

Comment: Specifying a default db isn't the problem, looking at 100+ dbs in the object explorer that I don't have access to is.  Seems pretty trivial and I've explored pretty much everything configurable in management studio and can't find a thing...

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS you can now filter that list.  Right-click on the databases "folder" and add a filter as desired:

[image]

Looks like you can filter tables, views, procedures, and functions too...but databases will be the most useful one, I suspect.